# How can i change the state of a widget from and external class

Tags: flutter

I created a widget button class that resizes and shows a progress button when clicked. After some time it'll show an error or success message, based on the state in the widget class.

These are the three different states:

[image: State Failure]
[image: State Success]
[image: State Loading]

This is the source of the custom progress button:

```
class ProgressButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final int state;
  final String text;

  ProgressButton({
    Key key,
    this.text,
    this.state,
    this.onPressed,
  })  : assert(state >= 0),
        assert(text != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProgressButtonState createState() => _ProgressButtonState();
}

class _ProgressButtonState extends State<ProgressButton>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  static _ProgressButtonState of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<_ProgressButtonState>());

  int state = 0;
  Animation _animation;
  double width = double.infinity;

  double unchangedInit = 0.0;

  double initialWidth = 0.0;

  GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();

  String btnText = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    btnText = widget.text;
    state = widget.state;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      key: globalKey,
      height: 48.0,
      width: width,
      child: RaisedButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        color:
            state == 2 ? Colors.green : state == 3 ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ),
        child: buildButtonChild(),
        onPressed: widget.onPressed,
      ),
    );
  }

  void animateButton() {
    unchangedInit = 411.42857142857144;

    initialWidth = globalKey.currentContext.size.width;

    var controller = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(microseconds: 2000), vsync: this);
    _animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          width = initialWidth - ((initialWidth - 48.0) * _animation.value);
        });
      });

    controller.forward();

    setState(() {
      state = 1;
    });

    //Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 3300), () {
    //setState(() {
    //state = 3;
    //});
    //});
  }

  Widget buildButtonChild() {
    print(state);
    if (state == 0) {
      return Text(
        btnText,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
      );
    } else if (state == 1) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: 36.0,
        width: 36.0,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          value: null,
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
        ),
      );
    } else if (state == 2) {
      return Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white);
    } else {
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 5300), () {
        var controller = AnimationController(
            duration: Duration(microseconds: 2000), vsync: this);
        _animation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(controller)
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });

        controller.forward();
      });

      return Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white);
    }
  }
}
```

This is another class where I called the progress button:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<HomePage> {
  int x = 3;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: new Center(
        child: ProgressButton(
          text: 'Bassey',
          state: x,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              x = 2;

              ProgressButton.of(context).state = 2;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Over in the `HomePage` class, I tried changing state of a button by having a variable called `state` and passing it into the `ProgressButton` state property, which worked, but the problem is changing it. when ever the ProgressButton is clicked, I put a `setstate` function which changes the state variables number to another, but this time around it doesnt change the visuals of the buttom.

How can I change the state of the button from an external class?

Comment: Do you want to animate the state change between the three different modes, or should the button simply change?

Comment: @Niklas i also want to animate it sir

Comment: In my opinion accessing the local state of a component from outside of its scope feels a little dirty. One way could be to create a Stream that can be accessed by any component. Your progress button can use StreamBuilder and then change its state based on the value of the Stream. And your HomePage can simply write to the Stream when it wants to change the state of the component.